# How to obtain the asymptote formula of $\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sqrt[n]{\cos x}\,dx$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

I want to obtain the formula in the form as follows:

$$ \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sqrt[n]{\cos x}\,dx=A+\frac{B}{n}+\frac{C}{n^2}+\frac{D}{n^3}+o\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right).$$
At least, it holds that $$\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sqrt[n]{\cos x}\,dx = \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sqrt[n]{\sin x}\,dx = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{u^{1/n}}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}\,du = \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{1}(1-t)^{-\frac{1}{2}}t^{-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2n}}\,dt=\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2n}\right)}{2\,\Gamma\left(1+\frac{1}{2n}\right)},$$
but how to go on with this?

Answer (score 4):

You properly wrote
$$I_n=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sqrt[n]{\cos x}\,dx =\frac{\sqrt \pi}2\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2n}\right)}{\Gamma\left(1+\frac{1}{2n}\right)}$$ Now, take logarithms for the gamma functions, useStirling approximation of the gamma function and continue with Taylor expansions to get
$$\log \left(\frac{\Gamma \left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2n}\right)}{\Gamma \left(1+\frac{1}{2
   n}\right)}\right)=\frac{\log (\pi )}{2}-\frac{\log (2)}{n}+\frac{\pi ^2}{24 n^2}-\frac{\zeta (3)}{4
   n^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right)$$
Take the exponential
$$\frac{\Gamma \left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2n}\right)}{\Gamma \left(1+\frac{1}{2
   n}\right)}=\sqrt{\pi }-\frac{\sqrt{\pi } \log (2)}{n}+\frac{\sqrt{\pi } \left(\pi ^2+12 \log
   ^2(2)\right)}{24 n^2}-\frac{\sqrt{\pi } \left(6 \zeta (3)+4 \log ^3(2)+\pi ^2
   \log (2)\right)}{24 n^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right)$$

$$I_n=\frac{\pi }{2}-\frac{\pi  \log (2)}{2 n}+\frac{\pi ^3+12 \pi  \log ^2(2)}{48
   n^2}-\frac{6 \pi  \zeta (3)+4 \pi  \log ^3(2)+\pi ^3 \log (2)}{48
   n^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right)$$

Comment: Thank you， sir！ It would be more helpful if you could give more steps for your second formula.

Comment: @mengdie1982. It is just Taylor using $a=e^{\log(a)}$

Comment: I refer to $$\log \left(\frac{\Gamma \left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2n}\right)}{\Gamma \left(1+\frac{1}{2
   n}\right)}\right)=\frac{\log (\pi )}{2}-\frac{\log (2)}{n}+\frac{\pi ^2}{24 n^2}-\frac{\zeta (3)}{4
   n^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right)$$

Comment: @mengdie1982. Write $\log(a/b)=\log(a)-\log(b)$, use Stirling for $\log(\Gamma(q))$; replace $q$ by what is required; continue with Taylor expansions.

Answer (score 2):

A different approach would be as follows:

$$I= \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \cos^{\frac1n} (x) dx $$
$$= \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} e^{\frac{\ln(\cos (x))}{n}} dx $$
$$= \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sum_{k\ge 0} \frac{(\ln(\cos x))^k}{k!n^k} dx $$
$$=  \sum_{k\ge 0} \frac{1}{n^k}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{(\ln(\cos x))^k}{k!} dx $$
$$=  \frac{\pi}{2} - \frac1n\frac{\pi}{2}\ln(2)+\frac{1}{n^2}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{(\ln(\cos x))^2}{2} dx+\frac{1}{n^3}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{(\ln(\cos x))^3}{6} dx +o\left( \frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$
I don't know if those integrals have a nice closed form, but they should not be too hard to do numerically.

Comment: These integrals are difficult  to compute (even with a CAS) but, by the end $$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{(\ln(\cos x))^2}{2} ,dx=\frac{1}{48} \left(\pi ^3+3 \pi  \log ^2(4)\right)$$ $$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{(\ln(\cos x))^3}{6} ,dx=-\frac{1}{96} \pi  \left(12 \zeta (3)+\log ^3(4)+\pi ^2 \log (4)\right))$$